# breadcrumb-plugin for vue-spa

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, breadcrumbs

I need to implement breadcrumbs for my vue-spa project.
They need to be able to display properties as breadcrumb-items. Also, the parts of any route should be correctly identified as breadcrumb-items and should have a redirect that doesn't have to be written directly into the route.

Does anyone know of a vue-plugin that fits the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other vue components that you can use, with a better documentation.

- [vue-2-crumbs](https://github.com/Suruat/vue-2-crumbs)
- [vue-2-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/Scrum/vue-2-breadcrumbs)

Answer (score 1):

Breadcrumb are similar to navigation but here user know at which step he/she is.
In **Vue** I have refered [this tutorial.](https://medium.com/@fagnersaraujo/automated-breadcrumbs-with-vuejs-7e1051de8028)

`npm` package module: [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-breadcrumbs)

I hope your requirement will get fulfilled.

Comment: With the setup from the tutorial, how would I go about getting route-parameters into my breadcrumbs? For example: Display a route like "/article/:articleName/detail" as "Articles -> Actual Article Name -> Product Information".

Comment: https://github.com/iFgR/vue-breadcrumbs you can find complete code so that its easy for you to match what things remain.

Answer (score 1):

I was happily using the [`vue-2-crumbs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-2-crumbs) plugin however then discovered that it didn't work with SSR so created my own component, and as a bonus turned out to be over 50 times less code.

**Crumbs.vue**

```
<template>
    <ul v-if="stack.length > 0" class="crumbs">
        <li v-for="item in stack" class="crumbs__item" :class="item.class">
            <router-link :to="{ name: item.name }" class="crumbs__link">
                {{ item.label }}
            </router-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:    'Crumbs',
        data() {
            return { stack: [] }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.buildStack()
        },
        methods: {
            buildStack() {
                this.stack = []
                this.addPage(this.$router.currentRoute)
                this.stack = this.stack.reverse()
            },
            addPage(route, first) {
                this.stack.push({
                    name:  route.name,
                    label: route.meta?.breadcrumb?.label || route.name.replace('.', ' '),
                    class: 'crumbs__item--' + (typeof first === 'undefined' ? 'current' : 'parent')
                })
                if (route.meta.breadcrumb.parent) {
                    const parent = this.getRoute(route.meta.breadcrumb.parent)
                    this.addPage(parent, true)
                }
            },
            getRoute(name) {
                return this.$router.options.routes.find(route => route.name === name)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And a little css to go with it:

```
.crumbs {
    display:         flex;
    flex-direction:  row;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:          1rem 0 2rem 0;
    padding:         0;
    flex-wrap:       wrap;
}

.crumbs__link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.crumbs__item--parent::after {
    content: '>';
}
```

My routes are setup in the same was as required for the vue-2-crumbs plugin.

This component does require that you are using Vue Router.